# Proxy nodej.js HTTP Server to another node.js HTTP Server which is connected as client

Tags: node.js, http, express, proxy, socket.io

I have an local node.js HTTP Server which is connected to an extern node.js express Server using socket.io-client. 
I want to proxy incoming requests on the extern server to the local server which is connected as client to the extern server.

- extern Client (e.g. Android-App) connects to extern Server
- local Server (x) connects to extern Server
- extern Client calls "proxy_to_local_x" on extern Server
- extern Server proxies all proxy_traffic to Server x and backwards

How can I implement the proxy to a connected client socket?

Comment: You want to redirect, or proxy?

Comment: ahh i mean proxy, so I correct this :(

Comment: Alright, and if you're proxying... why not use a proper server for this like Nginx?  Why does this have to be done in your Node.js application?

Comment: wich such things like Nginx I cannot, handle security features on my own code, and use my specific adjusted connection-protocol, other think I do not proxy to public server, I want to proxy to a client which is local server

Comment: also I have n many local servers for which I need the proxy based on which one the initiated client (e.g. android/ios app) requested